# How do I do Zone 2 training / low intensity training precise enough?

Tags: cardio, lactate-threshold

Peter Attia does "Zone 2" training on an indoor bike so that he has precise control on wattage and HR.

So my question is: How precise does low-intensity training have to be to have the same type of results without more side effects.

Also, can I combine it with other types of activities?  When I go to the gym, for example, it could be nice to do short sessions on different machines before starting a steady state session on the bike, or 20min varied walking and then 20min on bike.
(The idea is that then I would already be a bit fatigued so I can achieve "Zone 2" results in a shorter time).

I see Youtube videos with runners only looking at HR, of course, they do not have something like wattage.

I am not in good shape, so I would think it can be less precise, and shorter, in the beginning.

With Zone training, I mean training at the threshold of lactic acid buildup over some period of time (ca 30 min and up)
[Peter Attia Youtube video](https://youtu.be/txLrNhv8GW0)

I am looking for effects related to longer sessions, and also not fatloss effects.

Comment: What, specifically, are the results that you are hoping to achieve, and the potential side-effects that you are concerned about?

Comment: And what are the results of "Zone 2" training that you expect to see? What are the negative side-effects that you are worried about if you overshoot?

Comment: Because it is impossible to answer your question without this information. Obviously you've been told that this "zone 2" training has some specific benefit, but unless you actually tell us what this supposed benefit is that you want to achieve, we can't answer your question. Without this information, you're just asking "What heart rate do I need to be at to achieve my goals?" without ever telling us what your goals are. The answer will be very different depending on whether your goal is fat loss, performance in a specific sport, or something else.

Comment: @DavidScarlett Zone 2 is about certain health benefits and endurance.  Sometimes it is about calorie- or fat burn, but this is not a part of the question.  (SIde effects are normal negative side effects of training such as DOMS, just too much strain than I can take that day or just bad "steady state cardio")

Comment: @DavidScarlett "Zone 2" is not about training in Zone 2 HR range.